# Magento sort by special price (disounted product) on toolbar.phtml page dropdown

Tags: sorting, drop-down-menu, magento-1.7, product

I want to extend sort by drop down for special price or discounted product from toolbar.phtml

```
 <div class="sort-by" style="float:left">
        <fieldset class="sort-by">
          <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort by') ?></label>
            <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
              <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('price', 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> Price - Low to High </option>
              <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('price', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> Price - High to Low </option>
              <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('name', 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('name') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> Name - A to Z </option>
              <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('name', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('name') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> Name - Z to A </option>
             <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('update_at', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('update_at') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Newest First</option>
            </select>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
```

How I can add one more option for discount so products will sort by special price ASC?

Answer (score -1):

```
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('special_price', 'asc') ?>"
<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('special_price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"
<?php endif; ?>>Special Price</option>
```